# How to use a msi installer property in condition message in wix installer?

Tags: c++, wix, windows-installer

I want to use an MSI installer property in condition message in WiX installer. This MSI property set by a C++ custom action. I can set and get the same MSI property and value before calling the condition message, but it is failing when I use it in condition message.

My condition message looks like

```
<CustomAction Id="CustomAction1" BinaryKey="CustomDLL" DllEntry="CustomAction1" Execute="immediate" Return="check" />

<InstallUISequence>
   <Custom Action="CustomAction1" Before="LaunchConditions">Not Installed</Custom>
</InstallUISequence>

<InstallExecuteSequence >
   <Custom Action="CustomAction1"  Before="LaunchConditions">Not Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<Condition Message="message comes here.">
   <![CDATA[(MyProperty= "NO")]]>
</Condition>
```

Here this MyProperty is a string and returns either YES or NO and it set by C++ CA and this condition is failing in both cases. But I want to show this message only when the MyProperty is set to "NO".

So how to use my custom MSI property in a condition message that was set by a custom action?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It would help if you showed your C++ code for the custom action that sets that variable.

Comment: I have just used MsiSetProperty() in C++ and am suyre it is setting the property value successfully. Because i can able to display that value in the above condition message. Even my question is how to handle this condition with this value.

Comment: try using a public property, i.e. "MY_PROPERTY", to make sure its value from InstallUISequence is passing to InstallExecuteSequence, otherwise on InstallExecuteSequence you will get the default property value. From that I see, if you understood correctly your request, the condition is set correctly.